# Command Substitution and variables

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

I'm running into an issue with command substitution that I'd like help with. I have a few processes that create a text file with commands that need to be executed.

File1.txt

```
Command_ID|Command_Name|Command
112121|Export XML Components|/Scripts/Export_XML.sh "Argument1" "Argument2"
112122|Test XML integrity|/Scripts/Test_XML.sh "Argument1" "Argument2" "Argument3"
```

My Script to execute these commands reads File1.txt and tries to execute the command in the third column using the following Command substitution. The goal here is to read and execute the commands sequentially and update a table with their return strings and return codes. I also have logic in the script to stop processing if a non-zero return code is encountered and store the current line number. This way the script can be restarted from the failed line after the issue has been addressed

```
VAR_File=/files/File1.txt

while IFS=$'|' read -r -a myArray
do
 echo "${myArray[2]}"
 VAR_Command="${myArray[2]}"
 VAR_Return_String=$("${VAR_Command}")
 VAR_Return_Code=$?
done < ${VAR_File}
```

The commands where the Arguments have double quotes are not being executed correctly.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: It would be better if you could just generate proper shell scripts with structured comments (from which you could parse a command ID and command name), rather than trying to shoehorn arbitrary shell code into a `|`-delimited record. Then you could simply source/execute each script.

Answer (score 1):

In your script, `VAR_Command` is set to some string from `File1.txt` like `/Scripts/Export_XML.sh "Argument1" "Argument2"`.

When running `$(${VAR_Command}"` with this string, the shell attempts to execute a script named `Export_XML.sh "Argument1" "Argument2"` (with quotes inside the file name), rather than the script `Test_XML.sh` to which the arguments `"Argument1"` and `"Argument2"` are passed.

If you remove the quotes by replacing `$("${VAR_Command}")` by `$(${VAR_Command})`, your code will work as expected.

Comment: It *might* work as expected. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.

Comment: Thanks for the link giving the general answer, I found it very interesting!

The answer I provided works for the use case of the author with the example commands he provided. Your link will definitely help readers with more complex use cases.